# FreeIpa user access control on client level for the same server

Tags: centos7, openldap, freeipa

Is there any way to restrict users in freeipa like the following case

I have 1 freeipa server setup
I have 2 freeipa clients setup under the above mentioned server
I have 3 users

Now I want to only allow user 1 to be able to login on client 1 and rest of the users to be able to login to client 2 but not on client 1.

Thanks.